# Spring Mongo Repository Failure to save?

Tags: spring, mongodb, repository

I am having trouble saving a simple document via my spring repository. Here is the document:
package com.foundry.domain;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.GeoSpatialIndexed;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.Indexed;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.javabean.RooJavaBean;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.layers.repository.mongo.RooMongoEntity;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.tostring.RooToString;

import com.foundry.domain.location.Location;

@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooMongoEntity
public class Sensor {
    @Id
    String id;

    @Indexed(unique=true)
    String name;

    @NotNull
    String typeRef;

    @NotNull
    @Indexed
    private List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();

    @GeoSpatialIndexed
    Location location;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(style = "M-")
    private Date creationDate = new Date();


}
```

And in my test class I am doing the following:

```
@Test
    public void testSaveSingleSensor(){
        Sensor s = new Sensor();
        s.setName("Test");
        s.setLocation(new Location());
        s.getLocation().setX(12);
        s.getLocation().setY(13);
        s.getLocation().setZ(14);
        s.setTypeRef("blah");
        s = iSensorRepository.save(s);
        s = iSensorRepository.findOne(s.getId());
        Assert.assertNotNull(s);
        Assert.assertTrue(s.getId() != null);
    }
```

I essentially create a sensor, try to store it, then try to retrieve it immediately. What I do know is that the Location object causes it to not be saved. If I comment out the setting of the location object, it works. Here is the location object:

```
package com.foundry.domain.location;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.javabean.RooJavaBean;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.tostring.RooToString;

@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
public class Location {
    double x=0;
    double y=0;
    double z=0;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(style = "M-")
    private Date lastUpdate;

}
```

I believe it has something to do with my misunderstanding of the GeoSpatial Index. I'm assuming we can have other data (z and lastUpdate), but perhaps I am wrong. I haven't found anything indicating otherwise. More tests coming, but all help is appreciated.

Comment: One of the issues I was having had to do with the limits placed on the GeoSpatial index. By default the bounds of the index can only be between -180 and 180, which means in my tests, it worked. However, in my live scenario it was not working because the values were much higher.

Lesson: Be careful what values you are storing into geospatial indexes. It will not save them if they are out of range.